# Search in array by array of values in Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Document contains field Tags with array of strings, e.g ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]. How can I get all documents both with tag1 and tag2?

I've tried ARRAY_CONTAINS, but with this query, CosmosDB returns all documents with tag1 and all documents with tag2, not only where tag1 and tag2 are together.

```
SELECT VALUE files FROM files JOIN tag IN files.Tags WHERE IS_DEFINED(files.Tags) AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(["tag1", "tag2"], tag, false)
```

My sample data

```
[
    {
        "id": "23244d53-f4ba-4bf5-90a4-a4073a759232",
        "Tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "23244d53-f4ba-4bf5-90a4-a4073a759232",
        "Tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0bbd57d1-38cb-4094-81cf-33703448bbcd",
        "Tags": [
            "tag1"
        ]
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM files 
WHERE IS_DEFINED(files.Tags) AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(files.Tags, "tag1",false) AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(files.Tags, "tag2",false)
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": "23244d53-f4ba-4bf5-90a4-a4073a759232",
        "Tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Yes of course, but may where is some build-it solution to get rid of constructing query by hands.